# RaycastHit2D to hit an enemy when player rotates. (Using keyboard input only)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

new to Unity and C#. I'm trying to make my player shoot an enemy when facing him. I'm using RaycastHit2D to be able to hit the enemy. Here's the code:

```
 RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position (transform.position).normalized, (transform.position).magnitude);
```

That doesn't work for a long distance. My player character needs to be very close to the enemy for the shot to be recorded.

But apparently, the second argument requires the position of the enemy or any point to which my player is facing when rotating. I have no idea how to do that. With mouse input, it works perfectly but I want to implement that using keyboard because that will allow me to add a second player. I've also tried using big float numbers for the third argument but nothing changed. Please help.

I have uploaded a picture below of the game I have so far.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want;

```
float distance = 10f; // set as required
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, distance);
```